# The coaxial cable is claimed to show the highest common inductance (M) relative to any other cable configuration?

Tags: electromagnetism, cables, induction, coaxial

The coaxial cable is claimed to show the highest common inductance (M) relative to any other cable configuration [Henry W. Ott, (1988), Noise Reduction Techniques in Electronic Systems, 2 Ed., AT&T Bell Laboratories]. When I searched, I could not find many arguments that support / do not support this claim. do you agree, what can you say?

Comment: Can you explain what this "common inductance" means and how it is measured? I know a bit about magnetic fields and cables and I don't recognize the term "common inductance". I can say why coaxial cable has got a fairly high inductance per metre relative to other cable types but I don't recognize "common inductance" as very meaningful. Maybe post a picture of the page in the book?

Comment: Once you figure out what Mr. Ott's definition is (probably the inductance per unit length), then you don't have to seek opinions or "arguments" -- you can just do the electromagnetic calculations on as many cable configurations as you wish, and you'll have your own answer.

Comment: M is the current induced in ground with a separate current loop return path for the Center conductor shorted end to end. The shunted coupling is then the mutual coupling.

Answer (score 0):

Common inductance means inductance that couples the conductors magnetically only to each other not leakage inductance that couples the cable to the rest of the universe.

Comment: Inductance is a loop phenomena and the only coupling is C unless each conductor has a different current.

Comment: That contradicts the model of any wire in transmission line theory.  M is only present when you have more than one loop even if unbalanced source or load, the L’s may be different even.  Such as a single wire over a ground plane or central wire in a coaxial cable. Thus if you have a poor ground at one end the coax can have ingress that creates the differential signal from CM noise.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your first comment.